# Name the flying train in Chuggington

Tags: chuggington

When I try searching I keep getting taken to info about a suspension railway in Germany - not what I'm after.

I've been watching Chuggington with my grandson and he wants to know the name of the flying train, it helps people (actually they're talking trains!) like a superhero

Comment: of use? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuggington

Comment: :) That's where I found it.

Comment: And now the theme song is in my head for the rest of the day

Comment: @Alarion chugga chugga chugga chugga chuggington.... on loop in my head too.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe you are talking about [Action Chugger](https://chuggington.fandom.com/wiki/Action_Chugger).

> Action Chugger is a super jet-powered chugger who lives in the distant suburbs of Chuggington. He is a movie actor and part time rescuer.

[image: Image of Action Chugger flying]

Comment: Hey, yours was an excellent answer as well. :)

Comment: Thank you, but it was far too slow for Action Chugger! 

Comment: Action Chugger! Thanks all.....tbh I never thought of just googling Chuggington, I tried variations on "flying train"